# Ionic App Serve not opening the Chrome Browser

Tags: ionic-framework, serve

I am trying to create a new Ionic Project it is displaying No browser in the Ionic serve command.

The Image 1 Shows the Info of the Ionic
[image: IONIC INFO]

The Issue where I click Ionic serve it is just displaying "No browser" it is not opening the chrome

[image: IONIC SERVE NOT OPENING THE CHROME]

Comment: which is your project folder? and also please paste error as text _not_ image

Answer (score 0):

**Please Run This:**

> npm run ionic:serve --verbose

From your ionic root folder, it works for me...